# What would have happened when the Concorde's low-pressure emergency system brought it lower mid-flight?

Tags: emergency, cabin-pressure, concorde, range

My understanding is that the Concorde was equipped with a system that automatically lowered the aircraft to a safe altitude if cabin pressure was lost. I know such emergency never occurred in its history but did the Concorde have the range to make it to the closest airport if say this happened in the middle of the Atlantic. With a range figure of approximately $6500$ km at Mach $2.0$ and $50000$+ feet cruise, it is not clear that this bird would make it to land in such an emergency given it was terribly inefficient at low speeds and altitudes. What happen if this emergency had ever happened?

Comment: It flew England-Miami/Barbados with flightpaths arguably farther away from the coast

Comment: The [3 NAT](http://worldairops.com/NAT/docs/NAT_Interest_AFConcordeTracksMap.jpg) used by Concorde. You can see they are crossing the ocean by the North, closer to Greenland and Canada.

Comment: @mins.  Of course the NATs change daily, but it's true that Concorde always took the northerly routes.

Comment: Diversion planning in the event of a de-pressurisation is normal.  It is calculated from the furthest point from a suitable diversion on the route.  BA and AF would not have allowed Concorde to fly if it was not capable of reaching a diversion is this happened.

Comment: Is there a question that can be answered?  Or do you merely have concerns about the range of the aircraft?

Comment: @Simon: These 3 NATs were reserved to Concorde and, according to [IVAO](http://occ.ivao.aero/index.php?site=concordeatc), they didn't change.

Comment: @abelenky The title edit is precisely what I meant. I do not doubt at all that both manufacturer and airlines took all safety considerations into account, so I am sure the concorde had the legs to make it to a diversion airfield. I guess the answer to this question are the NATs showing that it never actually flew too far away from land.

Comment: Your original title was *"Loss of cabin pressure in Concorde"*, which is not a [***question***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/question).

Comment: @abelenky My bad, still familiarizing with this site.

Comment: @mins.  Wrong twice in one day.  I'm going for a lie down.  Thanks for the correction, I never knew that.

Comment: You might find [this technical explanation](http://www.heritageconcorde.com/#!concorde-pressurization-system/cf1s) and [this discussion](http://www.airliners.net/aviation-forums/tech_ops/read.main/310912/) interesting.  The designers had to solve a lot of problems because a rapid decompression at 60,000 feet would only give you a few seconds useful conciousness.

Comment: @abelenky A title is a title. Titles do not have to be questions, though there seems to be something of a fetish on this site for editing every question so that its title is a question.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: As originally posted (although since edited), there was ***no*** question at all in the title or the text; just some rambling thoughts.  StackExchange is a Question & Answer board, not a discussion board.

Comment: @abelenky I agree that the original question was lacking a question, too. But your comment was just that the original title wasn't a question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pilots had a clear procedure to follow for an emergency descent, but this procedure was not automated by a machine. (It's actually quite complicated because Concorde had no speed brakes. So it requires negotiation with air traffic control for a clear descent path---not much point in doing an emergency descent if you crash into another aircraft on your way down).

Concorde was actually fitted with very small windows, so that a powerful air pump would be able to hold a pressure differential against the outflow in the event of one window loss.

Hear more from a Concorde pilot at: http://omegataupodcast.net/2015/02/166-flying-the-concorde/

There are several diversion airfields on the transatlantic route; KEF, YQX, and SJF are the most famous.

Comment: What is the furthest Concorde ever flew from a diversion airfield?

Comment: @Senpai - time for a new question! That's standard policy at SE. One question, multiple answers, select the one most useful to you. Have a new question - create a new question, don't create a rambling discussion in comments. We're all about new questions!!

Comment: You wrote SJF but I think you meant SFJ.

Answer (score 9):

I'm answering a point in a comment by the OP, rather than answering the question itself directly - but I do think it's totally relevant.  Feel free to vote accordingly :)

[This list](http://www.concordesst.com/history/destinations.html) provides a list of Concorde destinations.  I am assuming that it is complete.  I have not gone through every route but looking down the list suggests that GOOY-SBGL (Dakar to Rio) is the route with the longest ocean crossing.  [This list](http://forums.flightsimlabs.com/index.php?/topic/4607-concorde-routes-in-current-airacs/) seems to confirm this.

Concorde did not fly the southerly Pacific routes, I guess because it would not be capable of diverting in exactly the situation you ask about.

Suitable diversions on that route would be FHAW (Wideawake on Ascension Island), SBNT (Natal), SBRF (Recife) and SBSV (Salvador).

[Using this tool](http://www.gcmap.com/), we can see that GOOY-SBNT is 1870nm and it's all ocean between them.

[Using this tool](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html), we can calculate that the mid-point of GOOY-SBNT is at 10° 26′ 47″ N, 026° 29′ 44″ W.  We can also calculate that the midpoint to FHAW is 732nm and the midpoint to SBNT is 587nm.

So a reasonable guess (without access to the original flight plans) is that the **maximum distance from a diversion** is to SBNT from the midpoint which is **587nm**.  Easily done, even at 10,000 feet.

Before the midpoint, I guess they would have returned to GOOY since it is closer than FHAW.  Therefore, I also guess that FHAW would only have been considered if SBNT **and** GOOY were not available - most unlikely.

---

I have now found a longer one!  KLAX (Los Angeles) to PHNL (Honolulu).  This one's easy.  The Great Circle mapper shows us it's 2220nm.  There is nowhere to divert between those two so the new greatest distance is **1110nm**.

Concordes' max range was about 3900nm so as long as it was about 60% efficient at 10,000 feet compared to cruise (1110 / ( 3900/2) plus a bit for go-around time), the diversion was no problem.  Although inefficient at lower levels, I doubt it was less than 60%.

Comment: Nice resource: I love those scheduled times, BA 001 : 10:30LHR - 09:25JFK, how useful would that be; sadly last time I flew BA 1, it was 0945 LCY - 1425 JFK :(

Comment: @Simon: those are the scheduled destinations. There were many others before 1976: for instance, I saw it with my own eyes at EZE in 1971.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Do you mean Buenos Aires?  That wouldn't increase the "over water" time.  It was part of the South American tour.

Comment: @Simon The airport is based in Ezeiza, a few miles outside Buenos Aires, hence the IATA code "EZE".

Comment: @Calchas Yep, got it, thank you.  And you're right about those scheduled times.  Let's hope that hypersonic becomes a reality!